# Why does Gradient descent never reaches the optimal value?

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, linear-gradients, gradient-descent, supervised-learning

I have implemented a Linear Gradient Descent Example & have understood the formula behind it but why does it never reaches the optimal value and keeps on increasing the accuracy by updating latter decimal points. What is the definition or term used for this issue?

Is this due to the formula of gradient descent or a probabilistic & statistics calculation which never let it reach 100% and outputs 99.99%?

This is the code for Linear Gradient Descent on Node.js

```
const computeCost = require('./computeCost');

console.time('gradientDescent');

const gradientDescent = (X, y, thetat, alpha, iterations, levels) => {
  const m = y.length;
  var theta = thetat;
  var jHistory = [Infinity];
  var thetaHistory = [];
  var limit = 0;
  var cc = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
    var theta0 = theta[0];
    var theta1 = theta[1];
    const hThetaY = X.map((val,i) => {
      const hTheta = theta[0] + theta[1]*val;
      return hTheta-y[i];
    });
    const sum0 = hThetaY.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    theta0 = theta0 - (alpha/m) * sum0;
    var sum1 = 0;
    hThetaY.forEach((val,i) => {
      sum1 += val*X[i];
    });
    theta1 = theta1 - (alpha/m) * sum1;
    cc++;
    var J = computeCost(X, y, [theta0, theta1]);
    jHistory.push(J);
    theta = [theta0, theta1];
    thetaHistory.push(...theta);
    if (J === 0 || Math.abs(J - jHistory[i-1]) < Number(`1e-${levels}`)) {
      console.log('CC:', cc);
      console.log('-------------------',{iterations: i});
      jHistory.shift();
      return {theta, jHistory, thetaHistory};
    }
  }
  console.log('CC:', cc);
  jHistory.shift();
  return {jHistory, theta, thetaHistory};
};
console.timeEnd('gradientDescent');
module.exports = gradientDescent;
```

Given the Data:

```
var X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
```

Any Human can understand the Line is **2x-1**

For Example:
The values of Theta0 keep on updating as:
0.26833333333333337,
1.794529145018259,
1.8698473883049052,
1.9175566659682246,
1.9476819685001623

The actual value should arrive at 2 but it never does.

The Diagram is as follows: 
[Theta0 History Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5wsB.png)

Comment: Can you kindly post your code to get a better understanding of what you've done. Also Is your gradient descent increasing?

Comment: @thilakshiK Updated the Question, Please see if you could answer.

Comment: If you're trying to set your `theta0` and `theta1` values to the exact values in `2x - 1` , then you end up getting your cost value as zero. J = 0 doesn't mean your  cost function is working correctly. It means that your training data perfectly fits to your model but this doesn't mean your test set will also fit perfectly. I hope you know about model over fitting. You can increase the number of iterations in order to bring the value near to 2.

Comment: @thilakshiK - That's what I am trying to do J = 0, which in turn predict future samples with 100% accuracy rather than a value of 1.99x - 0.99 which when given Higher value inputs of 10000 to predict, the error will be large. That's my question from starting that why it doesn't reach the optimal value of 2. After a million iteration it still doesn't reach the value, so what is this definition or term for this issue, I'm asking that only.

Answer (score 2):

The gradient descent is a general optimization algorithm, which is based on iterations. We get closer to the cost function minimum in each steps (if the gradient descent algorithm is working). You can think of it like walking down from the hill. Every iteration is like one step closer to the bottom of the hill.

[image]

Why we are going down to the hill? Because it is steep, mathematically speaking the derivative of the cost function in a given point is large. As you move closer to the minimum (in each iteration) the derivative of the given point (the steepness of the hill) gets smaller and smaller. Therefore we slow down in each iteration. Also the learning rate control how big the step is. Notice that if we step too big we could end up the other side of the hill.

[image]

Because of the learning rate and the derivative of the cost function (and also the local minimum) could not allow us to reach the global minimum (hypothetically speaking if we give infinite time we could reach it).

If you use one dimensional data (simple linear regression scenario), then check out the ordinary least square method: [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)

| Ordinary Least Square formula |
| --- |
| [image] |

I wrote some code and it reached the exact theta values (2, -1) for your given data. Give it a try!

```
const ordinaryLeastSquare = (X, y) =>{
  let x_sum = 0;
  let y_sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    x_sum += X[i];
    y_sum += y[i];
  }

  let x_mean = x_sum / X.length;
  let y_mean = y_sum / y.length;
  let multiplier = 0;
  let divider = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    multiplier += (X[i] - x_mean)*(y[i] - y_mean);
    divider += (X[i] - x_mean) * (X[i] - x_mean);
  }

  let theta1 = multiplier / divider;
  let theta0 = y_mean - theta1 * x_mean;
  
  console.log('theta1: ' + theta1)
  console.log('theta0: ' + theta0)
}

var X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
ordinaryLeastSquare(X, y);
```